# How to list autocomplete suggestions as text instead of links

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I got this code from a tutorial that I am following for Elasticsearch and AngularJS.

Trying to figure out how to have the autocomplete function form a list of sugggestions in a dropdown as user input is typed instead of displaying links as suggestions.

Here is the html markup:

```
<ul class="suggestions" ng-show="showAutocomplete">
      <li ng-repeat="suggestion in autocomplete.suggestions" ng-show="suggestion.options.length > 0">
        <a href="#" ng-mousedown="searchForSuggestion()"><small>Search for &mdash;</small> {{suggestion.options[0].text}}</a>
<li ng-repeat="result in autocomplete.results">
    <a href="https://www.example.com/all/?search={{result._source.title}}">{{result._source.title}}</a>
  </li>
```

Here is the js:

```
    //Autocomplete
  $scope.autocomplete = {
    suggestions: []
  };
  $scope.showAutocomplete = false;

  $scope.evaluateTerms = function(event) {
    var inputTerms = $scope.searchTerms ? $scope.searchTerms.toLowerCase() : null;

    if (event.keycode === 13) {
      return;
    }
    if (inputTerms && inputTerms.length > 3) {
      getSuggestions(inputTerms);
    }
    else if (!inputTerms) {
      $scope.autocomplete = {};
      $scope.showAutocomplete = false;
    }
  };

  $scope.searchForSuggestion = function() {
    $scope.searchTerms = $scope.autocomplete.suggestions[0].options[0].text;
    $scope.search();
    $scope.showAutocomplete = false;
  };

  var getSuggestions = function(query) {
    searchService.getSuggestions(query).then(function(es_return) {
      var suggestions = es_return.suggest.phraseSuggestion;
      var results = es_return.hits.hits;

      if (suggestions.length > 0) {
        $scope.autocomplete.suggestions = suggestions;
      }
      else {
        $scope.autocomplete.suggestions = [];
      }

      if (suggestions.length > 0) {
        $scope.showAutocomplete = true;
      }
      else {
        $scope.showAutocomplete = false;
      }
    });
  };
```

The first list item in the html markup gives 1 suggestion (in the form of a link) and the second list item gives a list of links as suggestions. I like the list idea of multiple suggestions, but just want text phrases instead of links that the user can select. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, but I don't' have you object structure so I had to guess in a few places.

```
<select class="" style="font-size: 12px"
   ng-options="suggestion.options[0].text as suggestion for suggestion in autocomplete.suggestions"
   ng-change="searchForSuggestion()"
   ng-show="suggestion.options.length > 0">
</select>
```